# Как проверить доступность файлового ресурса?

Tags: python, файлы, ssh, python-2.7

Как лучше проверить доступность файлового ресурса на нескольких хостах, доступных по SSH на Python 2.7, и в случае необходимости создать там директории?

Comment: Например, целый миллиард методов: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638975/how-do-i-tell-if-a-regular-file-does-not-exist-in-bash

Comment: @m9_psy, автор вроде бы спрашивал про питон

Comment: @MaxU, а какие проблемы выполнить команду из скрипта на Python? Вместо изобретения велосипедов, можно воспользоваться возможностями, предоставляемыми ОС.

Comment: @m9_psy, а если надо работать с разными платформами? да и автоматическая настройка `passwordless SSH connections` в скриптах - то еще развлечение. В общем я бы воспользовался готовым продуктом типа [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) или [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/), которые кстати тоже написаны на Python

Comment: Действительно ли нужно проверять на существование если нужно только создать директории? Возможно стоит создаватать и обрабатывать ошибку если существует.

Answer (score 4):

Я бы воспользовался готовыми продуктами типа [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) или [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/), которые кстати тоже написаны на Python.

У меня есть опыт работы с Ansible - очень мощный и гибкий инструмент.

Но если так необходимо реализовать самому и в Python, то я бы посоветовал воспользоваться модулем [Paramiko](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.0/api/sftp.html), который специально для этого создан. Кстати, и Ansible и Fabric используют Paramiko.

[здесь](http://jessenoller.com/blog/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295551/how-to-list-all-the-folders-and-files-in-the-directory-after-connecting-through) можно найти примеры использования

Answer (score 3):

> и в случае необходимости создать там директории?

Просто попытайтесь создать директорию, например, используя [`fabric` модуль](http://fabfile.org), [упомянутый @MaxU](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/553492/23044):

```
from fabric.api import env, run, quiet

env.use_ssh_config = True

def mkdir(dirpath):
    with quiet():
        return run('mkdir ' + dirpath)
```

Пример:

```
$ fab mkdir:/путь/к/папке -H host1,host2
```

Эта команда пытается создать конечную директорию `/путь/к/папке` на узлах `host1` и `host2` параллельно. Благодаря `use_ssh_config`, можно использовать имена ssh хостов, перечисленных в конфиге таком как `~/.ssh/config` файле на локальной машине (чтобы ssh-ключи, имена пользователя, другие опции автоматом для соответствующих имён подбирались).

По умолчанию, `fabric` печатает вывод команды и прекращает выполнение, если команда завершилась с ошибкой—`quiet()` используется, чтобы работа продолжалась даже если `mkdir` вернул ошибку (например, потому что директория уже существует). Чтобы создать промежуточные директории, можно `-p` параметр передать.

Не обязательно, `fab` утилиту запускать, `fabric` можно использовать как библиотеку:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from fabric.api import execute
from fabric.network import disconnect_all

dirpath = u"/путь/к/папке"
try:
    created_dir = execute(mkdir, dirpath, hosts=["host1", "host2"]).succeeded
finally:
    disconnect_all()
```

где `mkdir()` определена в предыдущем примере. `disconnect_all()` закрывает ssh соединения к узлам.

Чтобы просто проверить существование удалённого файла, можно вызвать [`fabric.contrib.files.exists()`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.12/api/contrib/files.html#fabric.contrib.files.exists).

Если вам не нужны возможности, предоставляемые `fabric`, то можно использовать [`paramiko` библиотеку](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/) напрямую (`fabric` реализован в терминах `paramiko`). `paramiko` предоставляет гораздо более низкоуровневое API. Вот [пример кода как записать данные в удалённый файл, создавая промежуточные директории, если необходимо, используя `paramiko`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20294079/4279).